# why onNothingSelected is not called

Tags: android, spinner

Spinner item getting select on Activity start up

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                  Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The country is " +
                     position , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                return;

            }
        });
```

when activity start onItemSelected method getting called

I want when activity start there should be no toast message .Message should be displayed when user will select an item.

Comment: maybe u shud remove return command from nothing selected!

Comment: first i tried without return not working so i put return; and both are not working.

Comment: put toast within (if(arg2!=0))

Comment: This question seems like exactly the opposite of the title. Shouldn't the title read "Why onItemSelected is called at startup"?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. The question should be "Why is onItemSelected called when nothing selected"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use flag for maintaining that state. As your Activity starts the Spinner already has its first items as selected therefore its `onItemSelected` gets called on start up of the Activity.

You can manage it by this, take two int variables.

```
int first_spinner = 0, first_spinner_counter = 0;
```

Now when you initialize the spinner set `first_spinner = 1;` then add the Listener

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                  if (first_spinner_counter < first_spinner) {
                          first_spinner_counter++;
                    } 
                  else 
                  {
                     Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The country is " +
                     position , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                return;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the position .When the Spinner fires it selects the first position by default

```
if(position==0)
//donothing
else
{
// do your part here
}
```

Comment: Nice! So if the user wants to select first item in the spinner, he is damned :D I like the way you want to watch the world burn.